# How to get handling when error login(post json url) with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, error-handling

I want to make error handling when input wrong password or username.

Here, i use json url to post/login

I try to give redirect but still error

I have form login (index.blade.php) code like this :

```
        <form id="form-login" method="post" action="{{URL::to('/login')}}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div>{{ session('alert') }}</div>
        <p><b>Username : <input type="text" id="username" name="noRm" value="" placeholder=" Nomor Rm"></p>
        <p><b>Password : <input type="password" id="password" name="tglLahir" value="" placeholder=" Tanggal Lahir"></p>
        <p><b>Captcha  : <label type="text" id="mainCaptcha"></label><input  type="image" id="refresh" onclick="Captcha();" src="/images/refresh.png"/></p>
        <p><input type="text" id="txtInput" onchange="ValidCaptcha();"/>&ensp;&ensp;
        <label id="tickT" style="background-color: green; width: 25px; border-radius: 25px;"></label>
        <label id="tickF" style="background-color: red; width: 25px; border-radius: 25px;"></label>
        </p>
        <p><input type="hidden" id="resultCaptcha" name="resultCaptcha"/></p>

        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
        </form>
```

This is my route :

```
Route::post('login', 'userController@getLogin');
```

This is my controller :

```
function getLogin(Request $req){
    if ($req->resultCaptcha !== "false" && $req->resultCaptcha !== null) {
        if ($req->noRm !== null && $req->tglLahir !== null) {
            $client = new Client();
            $response = $client->get('http://192.168.11.183:8080/PasienV2/PasienV2/cekLoginRegistro/'.$req->noRm.'/'.$req->tglLahir );
            $result = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
            return view('login', compact('result'));
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->with('alert', '' + '<button type="button" onclick="Delete(this)">X</button>' );  
        }
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->with('alert',' False Captcha !');
    }
}
```

How can i make handling when user input wrong password ?

when i run my code and input wrong password, i got error like this :

```
"Undefined property: stdClass::$tanggalLahir"
```

[image]

I begginer to use laravel framework.. can someone help me ? Thankyou :)

Comment: I think you are getting it from `PasienV2/PasienV2/cekLoginRegistro` share other code also ?

Comment: @NikleshRaut if i try on browser, that url with wrong password, i got return data not found

Comment: please provide complete error response

Comment: @SurenderSinghRawat i update and prinscreen that error   ..